# How to get two divs below each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

My div is above the other and I used `display:block`and such but that doesn't work.  I am using the Vue js framework and I have a link to my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bLory9bv/)

I am also using flex but that doesn't solve it either. I thought flex 3 would help but it does not.

The code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Countdown</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.1/vue.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
<Countdown date="Februari 24, 2017 17:00"></Countdown>
</div>

<template id="countdown">

<div class="info">
    <p class="title">KNHB</p>
    <p class="description">Sprint 1</p>
</div>

<div class="timer">
    <div class="block">
        <p class="digit">{{ days | two_digits }}</p>
        <p class="text">Days</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <p class="digit">{{ hours | two_digits }}</p>
        <p class="text">Hours</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <p class="digit">{{ minutes | two_digits }}</p>
        <p class="text">Minutes</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <p class="digit">{{ seconds | two_digits }}</p>
        <p class="text">Seconds</p>
    </div>  
</div>

</template>
</script>
<script src="vue.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400|Roboto:100);
#app {
align-items: center;
bottom: 0;
background-color: #34495e;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top:0;
}

.info {
width: 50%;
height: 200px;
flex: 3;
}

.timer {
flex-direction: column;
}

.block {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
margin: 20px;
float:left;
}

.text {
color: #1abc9c;
font-size: 25px;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', serif;
font-weight: 400;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-align: center;
}

.digit {
color: #ecf0f1;
font-size: 130px;
font-weight: 100;
font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;
}

.title {
color: #ecf0f1;
font-size: 100px;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', serif;
font-weight: 400;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-align: center;
}

.description {
color: #ecf0f1;
font-size: 50px;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', serif;
font-weight: 40;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: what layout do you want? The question says "get two divs below each other". That doesn't entirely make sense. One div must be above, and one must be below. And what about wide screens - should they go side-by-side if the screen is wide enough? Do they have a maximum width, and/or a maximum height for different screen sizes? In other words, your requirement is a bit vague... :-)

Comment: On a side note, don't mix floats such as `float: left;` with flexbox. Remove `float: left;` from `.block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment don't use float with flexbox. You also need to set `flex-direction` on `#app`. Also I don't think you need to set `#app`'s position into `absolute`.

What version of vue.js you are using? vue.js 2 doesn't support `coerce`.

```js
Vue.component('Countdown', {
        template: '#countdown',

    props: {
        date : {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            now: Math.trunc((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)
        }
    },
    ready() {
        window.setInterval(() => {
            this.now = Math.trunc((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
        },1000);
    },
    computed: {
  countdownDate(){
return Math.trunc(Date.parse(this.date) / 1000); 
  },
        seconds() {
            return (this.countdownDate - this.now) % 60;
        },
        minutes() {
            return Math.trunc((this.countdownDate - this.now) / 60) % 60;
        },
        hours() {
            return Math.trunc((this.countdownDate - this.now) / 60 / 60) % 24;
        },
        days() {
            return Math.trunc((this.countdownDate - this.now) / 60 / 60 / 24);
        }
    }
})

Vue.filter('two_digits', function (value) {
    if(value.toString().length <= 1)
    {
        return "0"+value.toString();
    }
    return value.toString();
});
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
 
})
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400|Roboto:100);
#app {
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #34495e;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.info {
 height: 200px;
}

.timer {
 display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.block {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 20px;
}

.text {
    color: #1abc9c;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.digit {
    color: #ecf0f1;
    font-size: 130px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.title {
 color: #ecf0f1;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.description {
 color: #ecf0f1;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', serif;
    font-weight: 40;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <Countdown date="Februari 24, 2017 17:00"></Countdown>
</div>

<template id="countdown">
<section>
  <div class="info">
        <p class="title">KNHB</p>
        <p class="description">Sprint 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="timer">
        <div class="block">
            <p class="digit">{{ days | two_digits }}</p>
            <p class="text">Days</p>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <p class="digit">{{ hours | two_digits }}</p>
            <p class="text">Hours</p>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <p class="digit">{{ minutes | two_digits }}</p>
            <p class="text">Minutes</p>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <p class="digit">{{ seconds | two_digits }}</p>
            <p class="text">Seconds</p>
        </div>  
    </div> 
</section> 
</template> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

I also made few other css related changes, please check and let me know if this the desired outcome you want.

Comment: Do you know what coerce is in Vue 2.0? I am using 1.0.

Comment: If you are using 1.0 then `coerce` would work, according vue migration guide, computed properties are recommended to coerce a prop. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#coerce-Prop-Option-removed

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-direction: column` to `#app`.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLory9bv/4/)

And this is the fiddle after a little cleaning (removed unnecessary styles from `.block` and added flex styles to `.timer`):

[Cleaned JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLory9bv/7/)

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of divs is to stack on top of each other. If you remove all styles and use pure html, you should be good.

```css
#first {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#second {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">DIV 1</div>
<div id="second">DIV 2</div>
```

Is this what you intended?